# how to create @Html.ActionLink without href attrubute

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to create anchor tag without href.

```
@Html.ActionLink(@item.Name, null, null, new { @class = @className, @href = "#" });
```

output:

```
<a class="Category2" href="#">Category 2</a>`
```

exptected

```
<a class="Category2">Category 2</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own MVC Helper Anchor link to do that:

```
public static class HtmlHelpers
{
    public static string AnchorLink(this HtmlHelper html, string class_tag, string display){
        return String.Format("<a class=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", class_tag, display);
    }
}
```

Then in your MVC you can use it with :

```
@Html.AnchorLink("@className", "@item.Name");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to generate the url, than you don't need to use the `ActionLink` helper:

```
<a class="@className">@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Name)</a>
```

The main benefit of using `ActionLink` is that it will generate the correct url to the resource based on your route definitions. If you don't need that just use the anchor `a`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Category 2</a> ,
<a href="javascript:;">Category 2</a>
```

can you use it like this because its pretty much better.